# Text file in to columns and store in an separate arrays for each colum

Tags: python

Pretty basic script to read a textfile. I can read the text file and strip out the white spaces resulting in only have two columns of data. I can write data[0] to the b array and print it out with no issues, however, when I try to replicate it for data[1] and assign that to the c array I get an error that says "IndexError: list index out of range". Some of the files I'd be working with later have up to maybe 11 columns in so I'd like to understand how I could get this working for x amount of columns, not just 2. Thank you.

```
with open(file) as f:
content = f.readlines()
b = []
c = []

for line in content:
    # Get all variable-length spaces down to two. Then use two spaces as the delimiter.
    while line.replace("   ", "  ") != line:
        line = line.replace("   ", "  ")
    # The strip is optional here.
    data = line.strip().split("  ")
    print(data)
    b.append(data[0])
    c.append(data[1])
a = len(data)
print("There are " +str(a) +" columns of data")
for i in b:
    print(i)
for i in c:
    print(i)
```

Sample code because I couldnt get it working in the replies;

```
DESC: 

T:  

TGT SPEED TRAPS 1# 0.0000E+00 2# 0.0000E+00

TIME         HYH19986_T_DRIVER_BAG_PRESSURE
 -78.00000    +0.0000
 -77.92000    +0.0000
 -77.84000   -0.06355
 -77.76000    +0.0000
 -77.68000   -0.06355
 -77.60000   -0.06355
```

Comment: can you provide a sample input and a full stacktrace? your script looks fine so i think the problem is in the file, maybe you don't have two columns on each line or an empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: Yeah sure, the beginning of the file is;

DESC: 

T:  

TGT SPEED TRAPS 1# 0.0000E+00 2# 0.0000E+00

TIME         HYH19986_T_DRIVER_BAG_PRESSURE
 -78.00000    +0.0000
 -77.92000    +0.0000
 -77.84000   -0.06355
 -77.76000    +0.0000
 -77.68000   -0.06355
 -77.60000   -0.06355


I'd be expect to see the HYH19986...... and everything below it in the second column. If I just do a print(data) it displays it in this way; I'm thinking it has something to do with the empty rows at the top of column 2?

Comment: Do you only want the values where there are 2 number in the textfile? Or do you also want to store the "header" of the file?

Comment: I'd need the header of the file also.

Comment: What would you expect in the end in the `b` and `c` arrays with you sample data?

Comment: b should contain "desc, t:, tgt speed traps...., time, -78...." and c should contain "HYH19986... +0.000 etc"

Answer (score 0):

you can drop the while loop with `re` and change the number of columns later with `NB_COLUMNS`

```
import re
many_spaces = re.compile(' {2,}')
        
b = []
c = []
NB_COLUMNS = 2
for line in content:
    # search all contiguous spaces of size >= 2 and split
    data = re.split(many_spaces, line.strip())
    if len(data) < NB_COLUMNS:
        b.append(line)
        continue
    b.append(data[0])
    c.append(data[1])
```